# Create JPEG thumb image with general fixed header

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, jpeg

I want to create preview thumb for my photos like [Facebook's preview photo](https://code.fb.com/android/the-technology-behind-preview-photos/). My plan:

- **Sender**: generate a scaled thumb (with 30px max dimension) from original photo, strip out all fixed header to send.
- **Receiver**: From the "minified" byte array, append with the fixed header (hardcode in the client code). Then convert it to `Bitmap` to display.

Finally I come up with the solution base on [Q42.ImagePreview](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.ImagePreview.java/blob/master/src/src/main/java/com/q42/imagepreview/ImagePreview.kt).

I split these parts as fixed header:

- Start Of Image (`0xFFD8`)
- App0 (start with `0xFFE0`)
- Define Quantization Table(s)
- Define Huffman Table(s)

The dynamic parts are:

- Start Of Frame (start with `0xFFC0`): because it contains the width/height bytes.
- Start Of Scan (start with `0xFFDA`).
- Compressed image data.
- End Of Image (`0xFFD9`)

But it only works on 1 of my devices & not works on others.

So how to generate a **fixed, general & standard JPEG header** that can use on both Android & iOS devices?

Thank you.

---

More detail:

Generate minified data flow:

- Create a scaled bitmap from original image (max dimension 30px, keep aspect ratio) using `BitmapFactory` & `Matrix`
- Compress scaled bitmap with quality `64` using `Bitmap#compress()` and store in `byte[] thumbData`.
- Sub-array the `thumbData` above from `0xFFDA` to the end. (SOS, image data & EOI) and store in `byte[] body`.
- Prepend with the 4 bytes that repsent width & height to `body`, convert to Base64 string & send.

In the device that working fine, the size of `thumbData` is longer than others devices that not work. And the different is in Huffman Table(s), SOS & image data parts, see this:
[Diff check between 2 image photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ0Yg.png)

Comment: Sorry for my criticism, but using json with Base64 again adds 33% data, why not simply return the (entire) image via a separate url.

Comment: If we upload the thumb photo to url too, users cannot see anything as placeholder if their network is weak or disconnected

Comment: You might be right, you have a better insight. But providing an URL even in the message, that will invoke the thumb, is feasible, certainly in HTML 5 without new connection. An other technicality: _interlaced_ JPEG allows to present a thumbnail while still reading a larger image; but that probably will not be useful her.

Comment: _`"if their network is weak or disconnected"`_ I'm not convinced that this _"fixed header"_ solution needs to exist. Consider that Internet data packets are transmitted as **64kb** chunks. The largest file size I got from full color 30x30px JPEG saved at highest quality (100) in Photoshop was **23kb**. Consider how many total bytes (or percentage) are you saving by doing this, is it worth it? Does more compression (lower than `64`) give same expected byte-size savings? What device (or OS) worked (could check if they do internal "fixing" of bad JPEG data)?

Comment: @VC.One Because I need to send & receive the data packet with high frequency (as chat messages). The current full size of data packet is only **2-3 KB**, so I cannot let the data transfer slow down just for a "preview thumb photo" feature.

Comment: You could try compressing that byte array `thumbData`. Try the **Deflate** algorithm. See the `\\compress the bytes` code section of this entry from the [**SDK docs**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater). Then you can skip the sub-array and base64 steps. Also if you can find an LZMA library for Android you will get an even smaller size.

Comment: @VC.One It's unlikely that a general purpose compression algorithm like Deflate or LZMA would compress image data better than JPEG. Trying to re-compress the JPEG data through these algorithms will likely create an output larger than the input.

Comment: @nhoxbypass The Facebook article you link, says "*...the only other table that could change with different images and options was the **Huffman table**...*" (emphasis mine). This is what happens in your case. To avoid sending the DHT segments, you need to find similar "general" Huffman tables as Facebook did, and use these fixed tables while compressing. Unfortunately, I don't see how you can do that using `Bitmap.compress` (there's just no way to pass tables information to the method)...

Comment: @haraldK challenge accepted. You're likely right, but I wanna see bytes length proof. I'll try raw RGB vs JPEG thru a Deflate algo. I'll report results in a day or two. It seems the challenge here is to just fit a 30x30 image into 3kb max buffer.  PS: See my next comment below...

Comment: @haraldK PPS: I got the idea for deflate compression from another old project where they where using ZLib's Deflate for compressing video frames to transport a/v bytes for their chat / conference app. It actually helped, but maybe that's because multiple images (frames) or large ADPCM audio bytes give a better comp ratio...

Comment: @nhoxbypass Your max size is 30x30 pixels. As raw RGB that is `30 x 30 x 3` with a result of **2700** bytes. That is **2.7 kb** and is within bounds of the **2 to 3 kb** limit that you mentioned. It should be even smaller as JPEG. What is the problem? What byte size are you getting at quality `62`?... What about when trying _eg:_ quality `45`?

Comment: @haraldK The results are here: From 30x30 RGB or complete JPEG stored in `thumbData`... **(1)** RGB length = 2700 bytes. `thumbData` after Deflate = **2061** bytes **(2)** JPEG length = 1938 bytes. `thumbData` after Deflate = **1737** bytes... @nhoxbypass Are these numbers acceptable to you? With Deflated RGB, you save 639 bytes, which could have been the _"fixed header"_ bytes and so leaving a sub-array of just 2061 bytes. At least this way you don't risk **corrupting** the images with some fixed Huffman & Quantization tables. What's your KB limit as largest packet size for image sending?

Comment: @VC.One Do you have a link to the image data you used? Also, using fixed tables for encoding *and* decoding will not corrupt the image. OP used fixed Huffman tables *only* for decoding, that’s what caused the problem.

Comment: @VC.One If I don't split the **fixed header** & send the `max 30x30` image with quality `64` (using `bitmap.compress()` too), it still **works fine** both platform (and the size is only `1-2 Kb`). But what I want is even **smaller**, that why I need to split DQT & DHT as **fixed header**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that using built-in method of each platform. **The problem is in the compressing phase.**

There are a number of variables in JPEG compression, including the type and breakdown of scans, samples, DHT selection, and DQT selection. **If any of those are different in the encoder you use, you are going to get different output**. It's the nature of the beast.

For example: The Define Huffman Table (DHT) define how the "image data" (after SoS segment) was compressed. And you use fixed Huffman tables **only for decoding**, that’s what caused the problem.

---

So you may have some options to choose:

- Send the full quality image (without compressing) after scaled down to max dimension `30px` as preview thumb photo.
- Write your own compression algorithm or use a cross-platform library.
- Upload entire original image to your server to process & send back the "minified data" to Android/iOS.

---

**Telegram** has preview photo too, and their approach is similar to you. But they **transfer entire original image (in byte array) to server**, create a thumb photo, **strip out "fixed header"** and send back to the receivers the "minified data".

When receive on mobile, they decode the "minified data" to bitmap, by appending it with "fixed header" ([Bitmaps.java#L111](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/Bitmaps.java#L111)) & update image size in SoF segment. See [ImageLoader.java#L750](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/ImageLoader.java#L750).

Comment: How about compressing image in native code (C/C++), so it can use in both platform (Android/iOS)?

Comment: "@nhoxbypass I'm not sure, but you can give it a try. Because try compressing in native code (C/C++) is similar to writing your own compression algorithm"

Answer (score 3):

**Point 1:**

> *"If I don't split the fixed header & send the max 30x30 image with
>   quality 64 (using `bitmap.compress()` too), it still works fine both
>   platform (and the size is only 1-2 Kb). 
>
>
>   But what I want is `even smaller`, that why I need to split DQT & DHT as **fixed header**"*

- Make 30x30 image (Bitmap)
- Compress Bitmap into JPEG
- Remove DQT and DHT (optional step for even smaller bytes, but removing may cause issue)
- Compress remaining JPEG data using Deflate algorithm (basically ZIP'ing the data before sending)

**Point 2:**

These two images are 30x30 and use the exact same Huffman & Quantisation Tables.

[image] image1
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzptp9mmrhxxsq3/30x30_thumb_01.jpg?dl=1

[image] image2
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrvsybb564mw2vv/30x30_thumb_02.jpg?dl=1

Check if they display okay for you on iPhone and Android. If yes, then try these DQT and DHT tables provided further below on your own JPEGs.

**Tables:** (total size= 570 bytes)...

**Define Quantization table** (total size= 138 bytes) : There are two, each one begins with bytes `FF DB`:

`FF DB 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0A 0C 14 0D 0C 0B 0B 0C 19 12 13 0F 14 1D 1A 1F 1E 1D 1A 1C 1C 20 24 2E 27 20 22 2C 23 1C 1C 28 37 29 2C 30 31 34 34 34 1F 27 39 3D 38 32 3C 2E 33 34 32`

`FF DB 00 43 01 09 09 09 0C 0B 0C 18 0D 0D 18 32 21 1C 21 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32`

**Define Huffman table** (total size= 432 bytes) : There are four, each one begins with bytes `FF C4`:

`FF C4 00 1F 00 00 01 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B`

`FF C4 00 B5 10 00 02 01 03 03 02 04 03 05 05 04 04 00 00 01 7D 01 02 03 00 04 11 05 12 21 31 41 06 13 51 61 07 22 71 14 32 81 91 A1 08 23 42 B1 C1 15 52 D1 F0 24 33 62 72 82 09 0A 16 17 18 19 1A 25 26 27 28 29 2A 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA`

`FF C4 00 1F 01 00 03 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B`

`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`

**Point 3:**

> *"So how to generate a fixed, general & standard JPEG header that can use on both Android & iOS devices?"*

Try this:

(1) These beginning bytes are same for those above 30x30 images :

```
FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 FF DB 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0A 0C 14 0D 0C 0B 0B 0C 19 12 13 0F 14 1D 1A 1F 1E 1D 1A 1C 1C 20 24 2E 27 20 22 2C 23 1C 1C 28 37 29 2C 30 31 34 34 34 1F 27 39 3D 38 32 3C 2E 33 34 32 FF DB 00 43 01 09 09 09 0C 0B 0C 18 0D 0D 18 32 21 1C 21 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 FF C0 00 11 08 00 1E 00 1E 03 01 22 00 02 11 01 03 11 01 FF C4 00 1F 00 00 01 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B FF C4 00 B5 10 00 02 01 03 03 02 04 03 05 05 04 04 00 00 01 7D 01 02 03 00 04 11 05 12 21 31 41 06 13 51 61 07 22 71 14 32 81 91 A1 08 23 42 B1 C1 15 52 D1 F0 24 33 62 72 82 09 0A 16 17 18 19 1A 25 26 27 28 29 2A 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FF C4 00 1F 01 00 03 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B FF C4 00 B5 11 00 02 01 02 04 04 03 04 07 05 04 04 00 01 02 77 00 01 02 03 11 04 05 21 31 06 12 41 51 07 61 71 13 22 32 81 08 14 42 91 A1 B1 C1 09 23 33 52 F0 15 62 72 D1 0A 16 24 34 E1 25 F1 17 18 19 1A 26 27 28 29 2A 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA
```

(2) After above header's last four bytes `F7 F8 F9 FA` comes Start of Scan marker (`FF DA`) with 14 bytes:

```
FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00
```

(3) Now add your JPEG scan data up to ending `FF D9` bytes.

Basically in your `.compress()` output's JPEG, Delete all bytes from `FF D8` up `to FF DA + 12 more following bytes`. This way you have removed header and DHT/DQT tables. Send this smaller data and on the receiving side your app just puts header bytes from steps (1) and step (2) into some array then also adding your received bytes after the header.

Try to now load the re-fixed JPEG.
 
(your array should be a complete JPEG data, with bytes starting from `FF D8` ending with  `FF D9`).

Comment: what is the level that you use in `Bitmap.compress()`? I tried using your DQT & DHT. But it didn't work on my Samsung S7 Edge

Comment: These two image above, did you generate them using `Bitmap.compress()`? Do you have any example code so I can try on my device

Comment: Your solution have the same Huffman tables as Telegram, but 2 DQT is different.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I use quality level 100 for tests. I didn't use `Bitmap.compress()` cos I don't use the Android SDK. I can use Adobe's AS3 language to make APK files since faster and lighter than official Android IDE/compiler for my tasks of making audio/visual apps. This is the [**source of AS3 encoder**](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as) if you want to know how Adobe does it (setting DHT and DQT etc).

Comment: Can AS3 code convert to C/C++ code? So I can try using it in my project. Btw: thank you, at least I know it can be achieve using AS3 language.

Comment: AS3 is easy.. **(1)** Syntax style AS3 `var myName : DataType = Value;` where in Java syntax we say as `DataType myName = Value;`. Example: AS3 says `var A : int=0` Java says `int A = 0`. **(2)** Function return type comes function name. example `private function abc( ) : int` means this AS3 function must return an **int** variable. **(3)** AS3 datatype `:Number` is any number with decimal point. Java cold try `Float` as substitute... After those details everything else in encoder is doable in Java or C++. It's just mostly using ints and arrays.

Comment: Do you have the AS3 code that generate 2 image above? So I can try with my image.

Comment: Not on me now... but [**this is similar**](http://www.as3gamegears.com/misc/as3-image-library/) (just ignore PNG bytearray line). The encoder is a class that you import and initialise with `= new JPEGEncoder( x )` line (where `x` is quality number between 1 and 100, no `x` defaults to 100 setting). Encoder class takes input Bitmap and returns a bytearray of JPEG data which is why it's being used to update one array here with `var jpg:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmap.bitmapData, 300);`